# Index number of predicted data by keras

Tags: python, keras, indexing, prediction

I have used `keras` library and I was trying to get the index number of the predicted data having value 1, I build the model on basis of 1 or 0.
After training and saving the model

```
pred=model.predict(x_test)
pred=[1 if y>0.5 else 0 for y in pred]
pred
```

And the output i got is

```
[1,
1,
0,
1,
0,
.
.
.
1]
```

Comment: Can you descire the problem?

Comment: model which predict if the patient has a disease or not , if yes the I'll get 1 else 0

Comment: Please, be more focus about the problem